# Downloading mutliple images in an AsyncTask thread cause error

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm downloading multiple images through `AsyncTask`. It is working well when there are 2-3 images; but, when there are more images, many `AsyncTask` instances are created, and are causing errors. Do anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: you are loading images in listview ?

Comment: What is error, post logtrace!

Comment: Spelling, grammar, syntax, and naming of a  class.

Comment: really `AsyncTask` is fun killer for android devs and i highly recommended `Producer/Consumer` and use `buffer (interface)` as share object or mix `Producer/Consumer` with `callback pattern`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your code here?

Maybe you can try to use onPostExecute function of your Asynctask to start a new one like:

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
    doInBackground();
}
```

or you can trigger an activity function by your onPostExecute() function to start download " next picture "  so it will only create one asynctask for one time.

Answer (score 0):

> From Android Doc: Common view components such as ListView and GridView
>   introduce another issue when used in conjunction with the AsyncTask as
>   demonstrated in the previous section. In order to be efficient with
>   memory, these components recycle child views as the user scrolls. If
>   each child view triggers an AsyncTask, there is no guarantee that when
>   it completes, the associated view has not already been recycled for
>   use in another child view. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the
>   order in which asynchronous tasks are started is the order that they
>   complete.

[**Handle Concurrency**](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

```
 public class ImageDownloader {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "ImageDownloader";

        public enum Mode { NO_ASYNC_TASK, NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE, CORRECT }
        private Mode mode = Mode.NO_ASYNC_TASK;

        /**
         * Download the specified image from the Internet and binds it to the provided ImageView. The
         * binding is immediate if the image is found in the cache and will be done asynchronously
         * otherwise. A null bitmap will be associated to the ImageView if an error occurs.
         *
         * @param url The URL of the image to download.
         * @param imageView The ImageView to bind the downloaded image to.
         */
        public void download(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            resetPurgeTimer();
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);

            if (bitmap == null) {
                forceDownload(url, imageView);
            } else {
                cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

        /*
         * Same as download but the image is always downloaded and the cache is not used.
         * Kept private at the moment as its interest is not clear.
           private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView view) {
              forceDownload(url, view, null);
           }
         */

        /**
         * Same as download but the image is always downloaded and the cache is not used.
         * Kept private at the moment as its interest is not clear.
         */
        private void forceDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            // State sanity: url is guaranteed to never be null in DownloadedDrawable and cache keys.
            if (url == null) {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                return;
            }

            if (cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)) {
                switch (mode) {
                    case NO_ASYNC_TASK:
                        Bitmap bitmap = downloadBitmap(url);
                        addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        break;

                    case NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE:
                        imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                        BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                        task.execute(url);
                        break;

                    case CORRECT:
                        task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                        DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable(task);
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                        imageView.setMinimumHeight(156);
                        task.execute(url);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if the current download has been canceled or if there was no download in
         * progress on this image view.
         * Returns false if the download in progress deals with the same url. The download is not
         * stopped in that case.
         */
        private static boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

            if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
                String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
                if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
                    bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    // The same URL is already being downloaded.
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * @param imageView Any imageView
         * @return Retrieve the currently active download task (if any) associated with this imageView.
         * null if there is no such task.
         */
        private static BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
            if (imageView != null) {
                Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                if (drawable instanceof DownloadedDrawable) {
                    DownloadedDrawable downloadedDrawable = (DownloadedDrawable)drawable;
                    return downloadedDrawable.getBitmapDownloaderTask();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
            final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

            // AndroidHttpClient is not allowed to be used from the main thread
            final HttpClient client = (mode == Mode.NO_ASYNC_TASK) ? new DefaultHttpClient() :
                AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
            final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                            " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                    return null;
                }

                final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();
                        // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        // Bug on slow connections, fixed in future release.
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
                    } finally {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                        entity.consumeContent();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Incorrect URL: " + url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getRequest.abort();
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
            } finally {
                if ((client instanceof AndroidHttpClient)) {
                    ((AndroidHttpClient) client).close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * An InputStream that skips the exact number of bytes provided, unless it reaches EOF.
         */
        static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
            public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
                super(inputStream);
            }

            @Override
            public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
                long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
                while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                    long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                    if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                        int b = read();
                        if (b < 0) {
                            break;  // we reached EOF
                        } else {
                            bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                        }
                    }
                    totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
                }
                return totalBytesSkipped;
            }
        }

        /**
         * The actual AsyncTask that will asynchronously download the image.
         */
        class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            private String url;
            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

            public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

            /**
             * Actual download method.
             */
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                url = params[0];
                return downloadBitmap(url);
            }

            /**
             * Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
             */
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    bitmap = null;
                }

                addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);

                if (imageViewReference != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                    BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);
                    // Change bitmap only if this process is still associated with it
                    // Or if we don't use any bitmap to task association (NO_DOWNLOADED_DRAWABLE mode)
                    if ((this == bitmapDownloaderTask) || (mode != Mode.CORRECT)) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * A fake Drawable that will be attached to the imageView while the download is in progress.
         *
         * <p>Contains a reference to the actual download task, so that a download task can be stopped
         * if a new binding is required, and makes sure that only the last started download process can
         * bind its result, independently of the download finish order.</p>
         */
        static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
            private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

            public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                super(Color.BLACK);
                bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
                    new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
            }

            public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
                return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
            }
        }

        public void setMode(Mode mode) {
            this.mode = mode;
            clearCache();
        }


        /*
         * Cache-related fields and methods.
         * 
         * We use a hard and a soft cache. A soft reference cache is too aggressively cleared by the
         * Garbage Collector.
         */

        private static final int HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY = 10;
        private static final int DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE = 10 * 1000; // in milliseconds

        // Hard cache, with a fixed maximum capacity and a life duration
        private final HashMap<String, Bitmap> sHardBitmapCache =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2, 0.75f, true) {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest) {
                if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
                    // Entries push-out of hard reference cache are transferred to soft reference cache
                    sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(eldest.getValue()));
                    return true;
                } else
                    return false;
            }
        };

        // Soft cache for bitmaps kicked out of hard cache
        private final static ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> sSoftBitmapCache =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2);

        private final Handler purgeHandler = new Handler();

        private final Runnable purger = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                clearCache();
            }
        };

        /**
         * Adds this bitmap to the cache.
         * @param bitmap The newly downloaded bitmap.
         */
        private void addBitmapToCache(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
                    sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param url The URL of the image that will be retrieved from the cache.
         * @return The cached bitmap or null if it was not found.
         */
        private Bitmap getBitmapFromCache(String url) {
            // First try the hard reference cache
            synchronized (sHardBitmapCache) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = sHardBitmapCache.get(url);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    // Bitmap found in hard cache
                    // Move element to first position, so that it is removed last
                    sHardBitmapCache.remove(url);
                    sHardBitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            }

            // Then try the soft reference cache
            SoftReference<Bitmap> bitmapReference = sSoftBitmapCache.get(url);
            if (bitmapReference != null) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = bitmapReference.get();
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    // Bitmap found in soft cache
                    return bitmap;
                } else {
                    // Soft reference has been Garbage Collected
                    sSoftBitmapCache.remove(url);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Clears the image cache used internally to improve performance. Note that for memory
         * efficiency reasons, the cache will automatically be cleared after a certain inactivity delay.
         */
        public void clearCache() {
            sHardBitmapCache.clear();
            sSoftBitmapCache.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Allow a new delay before the automatic cache clear is done.
         */
        private void resetPurgeTimer() {
            purgeHandler.removeCallbacks(purger);
            purgeHandler.postDelayed(purger, DELAY_BEFORE_PURGE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [***Vinci***](https://github.com/abbashosseini/Vinci) android Library its testet and support `Concurrency` and its build on top

- Builder   Pattern
- Singleton Pattern
- Callback  Pattern

and its handle downloading multi Images by her self and its easy to use .

*if you wanna get a result of every download request :*

```
 Vinci
   .base(context)
   .process()
   .load(uri, 
        new Request() {
                     @Override
                     public void onSuccess(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        viewHolder.Writer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        //or
                        //do some thing with bitmap
                     }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                         Log.e(e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                    }
           });
```

*if you wanna show image in `ImageView` you can use it like this*

```
Vinci
    .base(context)
    .process()
    .load(uri)
    .view(imageView);
```

for use it in *`RecycleView`* see this [wiki page](https://github.com/abbashosseini/Vinci/wiki/CallBacks)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Picasso library, to load the images into the ImageViews, as this is very simple to use and also supports concurrency very easily.
Example:

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(url_of_image).into(imageView);
```